# Handle the body of a "POST" request?

Tags: http, post, browser, server, request

Im trying to set up a web server that receives and handles a couple of http requests. Unfortunately, I'm stuck on "POST" requests. Hope someone can help me here.

I have a form that I use to send a file(image) + some text fields from the browser to my server.

When I receive the request on the server and analyze the request body (which is below all "header" fields), I notice that it does not always look the same.

The body always starts with:

--- webkitformboundry .....
Content-Disposition .....
Content-Type: image .....

and then lots of unreadable data...

After the unreadable data it continues the same way it started...This time for the remaining fields:

--- webkitformboundry .....
Content-Disposition .....

So now I wonder. Why is the information about the other input fields only visible sometimes, and sometimes not?

Best regards

---

**UPDATE:** This is the form I use to send the request

```
<form method="POST" action="process_upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="user_upload">
    <input type="hidden" name="duration">
    <input type="hidden" name="test" value="test test">

    <button type="submit">Send</button>

</form>
```

**Server receives:**

POST /process_upload.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:27015
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 129985
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://localhost:27015
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary1JhkT5GiE89P2SBs
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Referer: http://localhost:27015/index
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: PHPSESSID=5motqqf425llf53j5hutj0a0bn

------WebKitFormBoundarymRYGcz75Ct8BV6bh
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user_upload"; filename="myfile.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

ÿØÿáÉ§¦¨ä"Ö]2üà©–=/D‰…Ë7]^ÃžXªë§¬–-zÆ‰x›Ž;?•?üƒî«û³o±Vôì°%²úŸà£õ'õ·òùÿmá±E~ßÝ°Ú×«Ç{NÉò·ƒLûúÌHøûs–ŸsÅ“µï²gÃi½î¢©ÇR»ŽE¼S^]þÏÿ

*//End of message here.*

As you can see, information about 2 input fields is missing (duration and test). 
Full content length is received and no supplementary request is sent

Comment: How do you plan to process the requests? Most Server-side languages full support POST decoding.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't want to mix in PHP or something else that handles this stuff for me. I want to learn how it is handled from scratch.

And also, how about the image that was sent, is it in the right format or should it (or the whole body) be decompressed. Or something similar?

Comment: I've added an update to my original post with new information, that makes my problem clearer.